# Como obtener los elementos de una lista por pares en python

Tags: python, lista

Tengo esta lista en python

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
```

Como puedo obtener los elementos por pares almacenados en una lista de tuplas. De esta forma:

```
[(a,b),(c,d),(e,f),(g,h)]
```

Comment: Hola Carlos. Revisa [esta guía](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y edita tu pregunta apropiadamente. En esta comunidad se trata de resolver un problema puntual que tengas con el código que estás usando actualmente. Si no tienes idea de como empezar, te sugiero que uses Google, Bing o Github.

Comment: ¿Quieres que el resultado sean 4 listas de dos elementos?, ¿quieres que sea una lista de listas?,... ¿Qué has intentado hacer para conseguir el resultado que indicas? Lo suyo es que pongas el código que has intentado e intentamos corregir ese código o te damos otras ideas para que el código haga lo que esperas. Modifica la pregunta añadiendo más información y te intentamos responder.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus indicaciones. Si formulé mi pregunta de tal forma fue siguiendo el ejemplo que muchas veces he viso en este Foro. Puede resolverlo de la siguiente forma: zipped = zip(lista[0::2], lista[1::2])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución genérica para obtener tuplas de `N` items a partir de una lista:

```
def troceo(lista, n):
    return list(zip(*[iter(lista)]*n))
```

Explicación por partes:

- `iter(lista)` obtiene un iterador a partir de la lista
- `[iter(lista)]*n` crea una lista de longitud `n` usando el mismo iterador repetido
- `zip(*[iter(lista)]*n)` pasa la lista como argumento, equivalente a pasar `n` veces el iterador. O sea, `zip(*[it]*2)` equivale a `zip(it,it)`
- `list(zip(*[iter(lista)]*n))` convierte el resultado a una lista (en python3, zip devuelve otro iterador)

Answer (score 4):

Pude resolverlo utilizando la funcion zip.

```
lista = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
```

Generacion de una lista formada por tuplas usando la funcion zip

```
zipped = zip(lista[0::2], lista[1::2])
```

Resultado para zipped:

```
[(a,b),(c,d),(e,f),(g,h)]
```

Comment: ¿Qué ocurriría si la lista original tiene un número impar de elementos?

Comment: Si hay un número impar, se pierde el último item. En general, `zip` combina los iteradores que se le pasan y genera una secuencia de longitud igual al del menor iterador. Si quieres que no ocurra así, puedes usar el [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) del módulo [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)